# ListView onItemClick horizontal progressbar

Tags: android, progressdialog

Surely this should work? I only get a circular indeterminate spinner. What am I doing wrong!?

```
 // Assume oListElements is a list of strings
 ArrayAdapter<String> oArrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,oListElements);
 oListView.setAdapter(oArrayAdapter);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> oArg1, View oView, int iInt1, long iInt2)
{
    /*
     * Also tried:
     * ProgressDialog oProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
     */
    ProgressDialog oProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    oProgressDialog.setProgress(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    oProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    oProgressDialog.setMessage("PD Message");
    oProgressDialog.show();
}
```

If you need it, my XML is simple:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TrainingMode" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ignore this, I just need to get around the silly Stack Overflow code / word check. Blah blah blah blah blah.

Comment: Haha thanks @still_learning - silly typo :) FYI: setIndeterminate() doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ProgressDialog.setIndeterminate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29) to make the progress bar non-indeterminate and use [`ProgressDialog.setProgressStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressStyle%28int%29) (instead of [`ProgressDialog.setProgress`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgress%28int%29)) to force the horizontal layout:

```
oProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
oProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
```